# Into exile I must go

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

"Ahch-To". No, [you did not need to say "Gesundheit"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahch-To). However, if you didn't, [you're getting off light](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120655/quotes?item=qt0309118) according to Loki.

I have grown intensely jealous of a certain elusive Jedi who had taken several years of relaxing and staring at rocks while everyone in the Galaxy was doing actual work. Apparently, he learned all the **right** things from Yoda.

So the Force is guiding me to follow his example (what, why are Jedi the only ones allowed to blame the Will of the Force for everything?)

### So, into exile I must go.

<strike>I would like to thank the Academy, my parents, and my coke dealer</strike> sorry, wrong speech.

I would like to thank the people who have made my time on the site good, better, great.

- Those who welcomed me as a brand new user and were kind enough not to close all of my newbie questions.
- Those who posted awsome answers that provided information about fictional universes I loved (or introduced me to ones I wasn't familiar with).

- Those who posted great or simply thought provoking questions, forcing me to dig deeper into the works I love and learn more about them than I ever thought possible.
- Those who expressed their appreciation of (what I hope was, to an extent, largely quality) content offered for other's benefit in my posts.
- I would also like to thank those who have had kind or encouraging words for me in the last couple of days. The only reason I won't name anyone is because I'm sure to forget someone and that wouldn't be fair to them.

  - I would like to single out @randalthor, for the last formal thank you, for a wide variety of reasons, not all of them recent.

Just like Yoda, my exile won't start the moment this is posted. I still <strike>have to deal with Padme's birth</strike> owe several people some answers, so most likely I will stop in about a week.

[status-exiled](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-exiled)

---

To avoid idle rumours in chat interspersed with the hushed "are we allowed to talk about this?" neuroses, I'd like to clarify a few things I anticipate will be hypothecized, aloud or not:

- No, I'm not ragequitting. I might return, although when that happens is... I'm'akjustgonnablametheForce again. What do you mean "The Force Doesn't Work Like That"?
- There are numerous varied reasons for me to suspend my activities on the site. Not all of the reasons having to do with the site in the first place.
- No, the moderators/CMs did not ask me to quit "or else" :) Or just asked me to quit. Or even suggested it to me directly.

  The only person i'm aware of who explicitly asked me to do this is the voice in my head.

  The fact that there is a voice in my head clearly should have been one of the reasons contributing to my decision.
- Having said that, some of the moderation patterns and actions by individual moderators, both recent and not, definitely contributed to my decision.
- This was **not directly caused** by the activity of a specific user that 90+% of those reading this post would suspect as the main reason.

  While the recent happenings helped crystallize my decision, the specific words uttered by a specific user were **NOT in any way the direct cause**.

  - To prove that the symmetry of the Universe is a mysterious thing, ironically, my decision was strongly contributed to by a specific user; that an overwhelming majority of those reading this would not ever suspect. I was among that majority :)
- No, the chat suspension  wasn't a factor **at all**.

  I honestly **do NOT object to the suspension itself**, at all (I do object to who got suspended vs. not suspended, but that's water under the bridge and not worth my time to expound on or anyone else's to read).

  <sub>Incidentally, to kill the rumour I saw going around and frankly, am a bit offended by, my recently increased posting activity had nothing to do with suspension EXCEPT that it freed up even more of my free time (on top of **year end vacation days off**) to enjoy researching and posting.</sub>
- I currently have no idea how long I'll be gone, and how complete my "gone-ness" will be.

---

- <sub>I'm not sure if this will affect official chat policy in any way, but in case it matters: people have my 100% permission to discuss myself or anything pertaining to myself as a user in chat, by name. No exceptions. No objections. "Be nice" rule would hopefully still would apply :)</sub>
- <sub>If anyone wishes to contact me, you can @-ping me on the site; or if in private, my email address is in my SFF user profile.</sub>

Comment: Every man must go ergo mango. Your answers have always been great from my first day on the site. I look forward to your continued greatly sporadic involvement with the site with your inconsistent gone-ness being minimal at times I suspect :) be happy dude!

Comment: Sorry to see you gone. Leave a map.

Comment: You've been a staple on this site since before i knew it existed. Sorry to see you go.

Comment: @CreationEdge - is that some sort of special case of Impostor syndrome that you're referencing? *rushes off to ask on CogSci.SE*.

Comment: @CreationEdge - and the point of this post wasn't to allocate fault, which is the reason I won't actually answer the question in your comment.

Comment: Sorry to see you go, DVK. You were a big part of this site before I even knew what it was, and really helped my out in my early days. I wish you luck as you enter exile, as you say, just like Frodo -- Dumbledore would be proud.

Comment: @DVK "the point of this post wasn't to allocate fault" - so would you rather I didn't publicly mention my strong suspicion as to who you mean when you say "ironically, my decision was strongly contributed to by a specific user"? Or does this come under "people have my 100% permission to discuss myself or anything pertaining to myself as a user in chat, by name"? (PS: a VTC on this - ah, the bitter irony!)

Comment: @randal'thor - actually, out of all the things, the VTC isn't entirely without merit. Obviously I feel it's ontopic or I wouldn't have posted (or, at least, as ontopic as many other things on Meta); but I can see how someone can argue it isn't. Re: your suspicions, I am definitely not telling you what to do either way. As I said, no restrictions, no exceptions coming from me :)

Comment: @DVK : Oh no, just saw this.  I hoped our discussions about the issues you've been facing lately would have helped your decision to *stay*.   Please come back!  :-(

Comment: @Praxis - for what it's worth, they definitely moved the needle towards staying (now that you outed yourself, I can admit you were one of the people I mentioned in "last few days" thank you bullet :) . Just that some other factors weren't able to be canceled out

Comment: Very sorry to see you leaving, and I hope it is not permanently.  Your many contributions have been invaluable, and, while I didn't get a chance to respond to your last message, I will say that I think you significantly underestimate how much the majority of the users here appreciate you, as a member of the community.

Comment: Which kind of exile is this going to be?  The Foundation kind of exile where you use your influence to trick the emperor into giving your project lots of funding, and send entire well-prepared starships to start a colony on Terminus; or the Purun Bhagat kind of exile where you just leave the community without any particular plan, and live as a pennyless wandering pilgrim begging for each day's food?

Comment: @b_jonas Neither :) I have zero influence with powers that be (even to stop behavior towards myself that would get people suspended if aimed at anyone else). I have a backlog of about 500 questions and couple hundred answers to give, so definitely not a "pennyless begging pilgrim" in the site context. I'm thinking more like Napoleon on Elba - comfortable kushy padded retirement. Or Bartleby and Loki... except i LIKE the idea of Wisconsin!!!

Comment: @b_jonas - on second thought, I just realized that both of the latter ended up with much bloodshed plot-wise. So as much as I like Wisconsin, I'll stick with my original plan of Luke@Ahch-To

Comment: But, you didn't disclose your real problem?

Comment: @SS-3 - there appear to be a couple of people who are absolutely certain they know what the real problem is :) Consult the experts :)

Comment: hmmm, tempted to ask a really good TFA question, see if we can get you out of hiding! If only I had a good TFA question to ask. *\*sighs\**

Comment: I think you should go after crossing 200k rep.

Comment: @SS-3 He'll probably cross it soon enough anyway - he has enough awesome answers to keep on repcapping for a while!

Comment: This makes me sad, as someone who loves reading your answers. However, I can understand the need to take a break - even not knowing your reasons, a break can be a good refresher on life.

Comment: Peace out @DVK. I enjoyed our winks and nods.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Thanks for introducing me to a world of science fiction I couldn't imagine

I just joined this specific **StackExchange** about a month ago. I don't think there is a single post by you that I haven't read. Your posts really (*and I mean really*) made me enjoy this site. I didn't realize how in-depth *Star Wars* really is, and to be honest, you turned me into a complete geek. **EVERY QUESTION** I had was answered by you in a way that made Star Wars seem fun and amazing. Although there are a lot of great posters here, you specifically stood out to me when I joined this site.

I used to read your awesome posts during class, and I still laugh about [*escaping in a Victory Oil Truck*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112998/why-does-everyone-think-that-the-millennium-falcon-is-a-piece-of-junk/113001#113001). It's a shame you're going, but I hope this isn't the last I see you!

Just be careful out in the world! Remember, **“It’s a trap!”**

Comment: Oh, snap! So *this* was the right answer!

Answer (score 30):

### May the Force be with you, DVK.

Answer (score 25):

I shall assume this is au revoir rather than goodbye.

[image]

Comment: *Vainly trying to comprehend if the giant "Dumbo" sign was a subtle signal* :)

Comment: @DVK - Merely a happy coincidence, I assure you.

Comment: @DVK Richard is happy because he would be able to beat you now. :)

Comment: I have a feeling this is just an ego moment for DVK.

Comment: @markrogers - Love him or loathe him, DVK has been a very big part of the site since it was a pup. His leaving represents a massive failure.

Comment: Oh I don't know, the site's not perfect, but people will always be coming and going.  Perhaps he's merely graduated to a higher level of fame and doesn't have the time.

Comment: @MarkRogers - "graduated to higher level", period. In a quasi-Buddhist sense. It's **quite** relaxing not having the pressures that come with my modus operandi as a poster, and not dealing with some of the less pleasant sides that come with certain angles of being a member of this community. Zen and the art of not answering :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Ha, it is kind of high pressure to post a lot.

Answer (score 12):

[image]
[image]

You gave thanks to a lot of people in your farewell post,<sup>1</sup> but the biggest one of all should be *to* you rather than *from* you.

## Thank you, DVK

- for your generally very high-quality questions and answers over more than 4 years on this site (recently I mentioned several of these among my nominations for best posts of the quarter)
- for your friendliness and good spirit (not everyone will agree with me on this, but I don't ever remember seeing you treating anyone on this site in a way I'd condemn)

  - You've been called 'abrasive' on this site, and (I think) even agreed with that assessment. But frankly, I like a bit of **blunt honesty** from someone who has **strong opinions** and **doesn't suffer fools gladly** - it's better than false sincerity, at any rate.
- for sticking around for so long, continuing to provide great posts to the community, in spite of everything you've been through (sometimes people seem to think having plenty of rep deprives one of human emotions, to judge from the amount of flack a lot of top users get - **it's tough at the top**).

### Looking to the future ...

Although you'll certainly be missed, and your absence will be keenly felt - especially by the many askers of Star Wars and Harry Potter questions (as well as the not-quite-so-many askers of Ender's Game and Hunger Games questions), and also by those who've come to know you and enjoy interacting with you here - at the end of the day, **you have to put your own life first**. I'm sure you have much better and more useful things to do than spend time on a Q&A site answering questions about imaginary people in imaginary worlds :-)

Hanging out on Stack Exchange is all well and good **as long as you enjoy it**. [When life is no longer a joy, a new perspective is a requirement.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26492525#26492525) If you aren't finding this site fun any more, then (much as it pains me to say it) you're making the right decision.

And after all, it's not goodbye for ever. You'll still come back (hopefully more often rather than less, and sooner rather than later) and still provide awesome content. When you do, we'll be waiting for you, armed with smiles and upvotes!

### One thing is sure: you will NEVER be forgotten.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>On a more personal note, I'm flattered that you singled me out for a special mention in your thanks, over plenty of people who've been on this site and known to you for much longer. It's a tough game to win your respect, and I'm honoured to have done so.</sub>

Comment: For what it's worth, the only tag I'm genuinely worried about being without experts in my absence, is "Starship Troopers", since the only person I'm aware of who's clearly more expert than me isn't active on the site anymore (Donald McLean (sp?)). Oh, and thank you!

Comment: "false sincerity" ... I'm confused.

Comment: @DVK No, I was talking on more personally rather than about posts, saying I prefer your "blunt but honest" manner to an attitude of false sincerity (not that I was accusing anyone of having such an attitude).

Comment: @randal'thor - define irony - posted wrong comment without checking canon :))))

Comment: @DVK Do you have any suggestions for someone who wishes to fast-track to becoming a *Starship Troopers* expert? I was thinking maybe reading the book a couple times and taking notes.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude - I have ideas, but if you phrase this as "what are good resources to become an expert on ST", I think it may be a good question for main site and useful to many people *hint* *hint* :)

Comment: Yours is most awesome...

Answer (score 12):

I'm sorry to see you leave.  I regret the fact that we butted heads, but I have enjoyed the times when we got along.  You're a great guy, and you have been an enormous asset to the site.

I hope you come back, and sooner than later.  SF&F owes you a debt of gratitude.

May the Force be with you.

Comment: TY.As I alluded to in the post,the chat events were nowhere near a big factor for me (the way they were handled in an un-even way by moderator was a bit of a bigger factor, but still not even close to the top of the reasons I chose to disengage, other than yet another indicator of how moderators here don't even try to enforce the rules equally). FWIW, I generally like a vast majority of your posts on the site and (silently via upvotes) tried to support you in your attempt to swamp the the RSS feed with Tolkien questions - most of the questions were of the "Damn I wish I thought of that" kind:)

Answer (score 12):

Awww.

The internet is a strange place. I really don't know you, or anything about you. And yet I'm quite sad about this. You're contributions to the Harry Potter tag have been outstanding and I have learnt a lot. Certainly, when I joined, it was clear I was in the company of a profoundly knowledgeable individual and whenever I saw DVK at the end of an answer (which was quite a lot in the Harry Potter tag), I knew it would be trustworthy and valuable.

*Thinks of Lupin at the end of *PoA**

Answer (score 11):

I am sad to see you go, and I hope you won't be gone long. I have enjoyed learning from your many answers on this site (especially Star Wars). Thank you for your contributions -- your site reputation is well deserved.

<sub>On the bright side, your exile means you won't beat me to answering Star Wars questions like you have a tendency to do. Your answers have slowed my progress on the gold Star Wars tag badge since I need to post 200 answers for it. Now if I could only get @Richard to go into exile, too, I'd get there even faster...</sub>

Comment: 17,000 credits should do the latter :)

Comment: @null - Given my treatment at the hands of the site's Community Managers and moderators, I have seriously considered leaving/going into exile. The jury is still out on that one, frankly.

Comment: @Richard I sincerely hope you don't leave, too. You would be sorely missed and the site would suffer from the lack of your contributions if you did. I can't control the actions of the CMs and moderators, but I hope that my encouragement for you to stay will help convince you to do so.

Comment: @Null - CMs and moderators around here sure have a deft hand :) What's the batting average now, 2 somewhat-valuable contributors forced out, and 1 maybe? :)

Comment: Ready.... start... POST! Also, I double-dare you to get a bronze tag for kylo-ren. I never managed to, for reasons you may find familiar :)

Comment: @DVK 48 more questions in the tag and you'll get it automatically ...

Answer (score 10):

The saying goes...

[image]

...and so they must

May I say ***THANK YOU FOR EVERYTHING @DVK!***

You've contributed so very much to this site and made it a much more knowledgeable place.

So, for now I say

[image]

and remember to

[image]

In the mean time, we shall all await the

[image]

Comment: Are you posting from 80s?

Comment: Also, I never knew Darth Vader's lightsaber was purple.

Comment: @MrLister you learn something new every day! ;P

Comment: @MrLister - prepare to have your mind blown. Kylo Ren's lightsaber was a **combination** yellow/red. NOT red. Source: WGA script.

Answer (score 8):

I hope you find what you're looking for and wish you the best.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I have been off the SF grid for a while, only answering questions in other sites, so I am really unpleasantly surprised now after reading your goodbye.

*To prove that the symmetry of the Universe is a mysterious thing, ironically, my decision was strongly contributed to by a specific user; that an overwhelming majority of those reading this would not ever suspect. I was among that majority :)*

Strangely I must admit I feel a bit addressed. Unbeknowst to the others we had a small number of run-ins on other sites and at least for me it was pretty clear from the onset that while we share a certain trait of directness our convictions and personal views are *vastly* different.

Given our differences perhaps you can accept something which can be easier
dismissed from a more friendly side: **It is also pretty clear for me that you were (and still are) an integral part and a building block of Sci-Fi Stackexchange**. I do not know if you really acknowledged it; well, you have it now from *me*.

There is an idiom in German: You can only appreciate what you had if you have lost it. The Great Suspension was really bad news, it teared a very large and conspicous hole in Mos Eisley.
I think one reason was that you really liked this site and this love was reciprocated. Therefore whatever you do, do not think lightly of your presence in SFF, it had a strong positive impact which will last a very long time.

Gesundheit !

Answer (score 3):

Safe travels. Watch out for any filthy mudbloods.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. Did someone really get offended... LOL.

Comment: @SS-3 mudbloods gonna hate.

Answer (score 2):

Oh no! You will be missed, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be some disingenuousness by officials, both by volunteer officials and by paid Company Men (CMs), on a site that works only when *profiteers* can sell *advertisers* the right to slap adverts on *other people's freely donated material*.

Those who don't want to be corrupted, who are here above all because they enjoy really getting into science fiction and fantasy, and mixing with others who have similar interests, should take an "enjoy it while it lasts" approach.

Thanks for all your contributions, DVK. Your enthusiasm has been contagious. That you're getting out or scaling down now, though it means a loss to many of us, speaks greatly in your favour.