# Please adopt these answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answer-quality

The following answers aren't 100% complete and [I won't be working on them after today](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7917/into-exile-i-must-go).

If anyone likes them, please consider adopting them and improving.

1. [Which predictions of the Force Awakens: Darths & Droids Bingo were correct?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112251/which-predictions-of-the-force-awakens-darths-droids-bingo-were-correct)

   I have completed answers to 70 out of 74 sub-questions.

   4 still don't have satisfactory sub-answers.

   Also, ~12 sub-answers are fine but would be awesomer if someone includes a screenshot.

   I included a complete list of suggested maintenance into the end of the answer.
2. [What are the things that “The Force Awakens” borrowed/parallel from “A New Hope?”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111224/what-are-the-things-that-the-force-awakens-borrowed-parallel-from-a-new-hope)
3. [Which things/characters do “The Force Awakens” and “A New Hope” have in common?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111228/which-things-characters-do-the-force-awakens-and-a-new-hope-have-in-common)

   They seems somewhat complete content wise but really could use TLC to organize them better than a flat list of bullets. Thematically or chronologically etc...

   They could also use enrichment; links and/or pictures, to be improved.
4. [What were all those visions Rey saw?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111972/what-were-all-those-visions-rey-saw)

   Needs film screenshots for the individual scenes.

Comment: You could always stay...and run to be a mod!  :-)

Comment: DVK for pres!!!!

Comment: I'd vote for you. I think you'd make a solid moderator.